# send an email after clicking the checkbox

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

```
I have the checkbox in the front end called "Ticket". If Ticket checkbox is clicked then an email will be sent to the reciepents.

Here I know who are the reciepients, so that is not the problem. Also email body is ready.

Only, I want the condition in the query when the ticket check box is clikced that email should be sent. There is also the hasticket bit field in table which I am using. So initially, this hasticket field will be 0. How I can achieve this?

This is the sample data:

Pass NO. hasticket   name
A1234      0          abc
```

When I click the check box in the front end, an email should be sent to abc.

Here what I have: there is stored proc sppass_update which will update hasticket field in the table. So first I need to use this stored proc to update the table. Then I can send the email. How can I acheve this

Comment: What is your "front end"? Is this a .Net app?

Comment: So, are you asking how to trigger this event in SQL Server or in your .Net app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Database Mail component of SQL Server:

1. Configure profile for sending your e-mail, e.g. using SSMS wizard.
2. Call `sp_send_dbmail` system procedure with your parameters to send e-mail using your configured profile.

SQL Server will send e-mail.